# How to use conditional control flow in awk

Tags: awk, gawk

I have a file whose content is like:

```
...
... Precision is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 due to no predicted samples ...
...
Score metric (precision_score): 0.0
...
```

where the line containing `Precision is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 due to no predicted samples` may or may not exist, and the line containing `Score metric (precision_score):` may or may not exist.

I want to use AWK to create a variable `precision`, and

- if the line containing `Precision is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 due to no predicted samples` exists, set the value of `precision` to `inf`,
- otherwise, if  the line containing `Score metric (precision_score):` exists, set the value of `precision` to the number following `Score metric (precision_score):`

I wonder how to implement that in awk? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not how this is going to be used but here is something that can get you started

```
$ awk --posix -F: '/Precision is ill-defined/{precision="+inf"}
 !precision && /Score metric \(precision_score\)/{precision=$2}
                              END{print "precision: "precision}' file
```

you can add the full text for the pattern.

gawk doesn't support "inf" by default, you have to set the --posix option.